# InSpec commands are too slow in Windows. Am I missing any steps?

Tags: chef-infra, serverspec, inspec

I am checking both Serverspec and InSpec for validating my infrastructure. 
While I was executing Serverspec in my Windows 2012 R2 server, it was working without any visible performance problem. But when I was executing InSpec, I saw no result for long time and I thought I did some mistake and cancelled it. Then I ran again it took very long time to run (a script just has one describe). Is this expected behavior in InSpec or do I need to do anything special?

My InSpec script is:

```
control "world-1.0" do                               
  impact 1.0                                          
  title "Hello World"                                 
  desc "Orca msi should be installed " 
  describe package('Orca') do
      it { should be_installed }      
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to an older ticket: https://github.com/chef/inspec/issues/86

To be specific, it should only be the package resource that is affected, not all Windows resources. We are working on improved speed for Windows over the next weeks, therefore you should expect to see this solved soon.

Comment: Thanks . seems it is known issue now and Work in progress for fixing it up.

Comment: The issue https://github.com/chef/inspec/issues/86 has been fixed via https://github.com/chef/inspec/pull/970. It will be included within the next release of InSpec early next week.